# What does また アリでも入ったのかなぁ～ mean?

Tags: translation

As far as I know that person is wondering (かなぁ is in the end) about something which happened again.

> また アリでも入ったのかなぁ～

2nd try: Still an good lesson for an ant.

Comment: Why do you think that 入った means "stepped on"?

Comment: Actually due to the また well at least due to the words which jisho.org shows up. Which means step over, but at the same time again. :/

Do you think the the person is entering something again? I always try to translate with bing translator, jisho, romajidesu, nihongo.j-talk at the same time, but this sentence doesn't make sense on one of them.

Comment: Please provide the context for this sentence. Otherwise all we can do is guess randomly.

Comment: She has something in her shoe, as far as I could tell.

Comment: She? Saying who "she" is would be part of providing the context.

Comment: She is on the way to the physical education. Before this she was sitting bored in the class room. It's actually a game, you are physically small.

Comment: This is all a manga, movie, newspaper column, novel?

Comment: Well, an illustrated Wolf RPG Maker game. If this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By utilizing all the information provided in the comments, I would conclude that the sentence would mean:

> "I wonder if ants got in (my shoe) again."